# alignment of two sets of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have a maximisation problem to do with aligning two ordered sets of 3D unit vectors.  I want to apply the same rotation to all the vectors in one set so that they are in closest alignment with those in the other set, in the following sense:

Given sets of unit vectors $(a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ and $(b_1, b_2,...b_n)$ I want to find the rotation matrix *R* that maximises$$\sum_{i=1}^n(Ra_i).b_i$$
Any ideas? At the moment my best solution is to generate a host of random rotations and select the highest scoring, but this is likely to be too slow for my purposes. Might there be an iterative approach to a solution?

Comment: Thinking further, this equivalent to minimising the sum of the squared distances between points on the unit sphere.  If $Ra_i$ and $b_i$ are an angle $\theta_i$ apart, then $(Ra_i).b_i=\cos\theta_i$.  And if the the distance between the endpoints of the vectors is $d_i$, then $d_i=2\sin\frac{\theta_i}{2}$, so $d_i^2=4\sin^2\frac{\theta_i}{2}=2-2\cos\theta_i$. So _minimising_ $$\sum_{i=1}^n d_i^2$$ over all rotations is equivalent (and seems like a more familiar problem...)

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm